# Process.Start giving file not specified error in .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I want to do printing in .net core.
To do this I am using `Process` of `System.Diagnostics`.
I tried following code below:

```
var printJob = new Process
{
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = path,
        UseShellExecute = true,
        Verb = "print",
        CreateNoWindow = true,
        WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
        WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(path)
    }
```

};

But `Verb` property is missing in `StartInfo` in .net core.
So then I decided to do printing as follows:

```
Process.Start("LPR -S ip -P 'Star TSP800L Peeler (TSP828L)' -o 'D:\testpdf.pdf'");
```

But it gives me

> The system cannot find the file specified

whereas the file is present at given location.

Right now I am trying to test with local printer on my windows 10 machine, but what I need is to print to network printer from ubuntu machine.

Can someone tell me, why I am getting file not found error.
I have found following link, but it is using StartInfo, which is not helpful to me in this case.

[Process.Start in C# The system cannot find the file specified error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38678576/process-start-in-c-sharp-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified-error)

[Error in Process.Start() -- The system cannot find the file specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369119/error-in-process-start-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified)

Comment: [lpr command not working from my C# program](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10554282/3060520)

Comment: [LPR command to print pcl-file from windows service not working](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11915241/3060520)

Comment: Now when I am printing to local printer, I am getting print server unreachable  or specified printer does not exist error? I am using following command:lpr -S my_machine_ip -P Star TSP800L Peeler (TSP828L) -o l D:\\testpdf.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this:

```
 public static void PrintToASpecificPirnter()
        {
            using (PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog())
            {
                printDialog.AllowSomePages = true;
                printDialog.AllowSelection = true;
                if (printDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    var StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
                    {
                        CreateNoWindow = true,
                        UseShellExecute = true,
                        Verb = "printTo",
                        Arguments = "\"" + printDialog.PrinterSettings.PrinterName + "\"",
                        WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
                        FileName = fileName
                    };

                    Process.Start(StartInfo);
                }

            }
    }
```